# Pseudo terminal will not be allocated error - ssh - sudo - websocket - subprocess

Tags: python, bash, ssh, terminal, client-server

I basically want to create a web page through which a unix terminal at the server side can be reached and commands can be sent to and their results can be received from the terminal.

For this, I have a WSGIServer. When a connection is opened, I execute the following:

```
def opened(self):
        self.p = Popen(["bash", "-i"], bufsize=1, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
        self.p.stdout = Unbuffered(self.p.stdout)

        self.t = Thread(target=self.listen_stdout)
        self.t.daemon = True
        self.t.start()
```

When a message comes to the server from the client, It is handled in the following function, which only redirects the coming message to the stdin of subprocess `p` which is an interactive `bash`:

```
def received_message(self, message):
    print(message.data, file=self.p.stdin)
```

Then outputs of the `bash` is read in the following function within a separate thread `t`. It only sends the outputs to the client.

```
def listen_stdout(self):
    while True:
        c = self.p.stdout.read(1)
        self.send(c)
```

In such a system, I am able to send any command(`ls`, `cd`, `mkdir` etc.) to the `bash` working at the server side and receive their outputs. However, when I try to run `ssh xxx@xxx`, the error `pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal` is shown.

Also, in a similar way, when I run `sudo ...`, the prompt for password is not sent to the client somehow, but it appears on the terminal of the server script, instead.

I am aware of `expect`; however, only for such `sudo` and `ssh` usage, I do not want to mess my code up with `expect`. Instead, I am looking for a general solution that can fake `sudo` and `ssh` and redirect prompt's to the client.

Is there any way to solve this? Ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Either use `expect` or go for `key-based ssh auth` & passwordless sudo (dangerous)

Comment: Is not there any chance to have a solution that can run all the commands together with `sudo` and `ssh`?

Comment: ^^ Yes, shell script is the answer. But if some command expects the inputs over stdin, you have to provide it somehow. `expect` is one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. What I need was creating a pseudo-terminal. And, at the `slave` side of the `tty`, make a `setsid()` call to make this process a new session and run commands on it.

Details are here:
http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html